# What are the benefits of self encapsulation?

Tags: oop, refactoring, encapsulation

While reading some refactoring practices I stumbled upon [this article](http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/selfEncapsulateField.html)

The author arguments to modify below code with getter and setters, I think they should be `private` but anyways what's the benefit in doing so? aren't we introducing the function call overhead?

Before:

```
private int _low, _high;
boolean includes (int arg) {
  return arg >= _low && arg <= _high;
}
```

After:

```
private int _low, _high;
boolean includes (int arg) {
  return arg >= getLow() && arg <= getHigh();
}
int getLow() {return _low;}
int getHigh() {return _high;}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say, for some reason you need to change the names of your class attributes from `_low`, `_high` to `_min`, `_max`. In the 1st version, you need to modify the `includes()` function as well. In the 2nd version you only need to modify the getters. In your example the benefit is small, but in a bigger class it could save you a lot of work.

A slightly more complex example where the upper value is no longer stored but derived from the lower value and an interval:

```
private int _low, _interval;
boolean includes (int arg) {
    return arg >= getLow() && arg <= getHigh();
}
int getLow() {return _low;}
int getHigh() {return _low + _interval;}
```

Again you only need to modify the getter.

Concerning the overhead: Depending on the language you are using, your compiler will optimize the function call away.

Comment: @LiSeeLeiCow-Q__Q: True, the code gets more verbose and the benefit is probably neglectable in most cases. I also suspect that if they do have a benefit, this indicates that your class is too large or too complex. I definitely do not recommend to do this by default but there might be cases where it is useful.